# javascript cycle function and dynamic img tags in mvc - also stopping with pagerefresh or setInterval()

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to implement the javascript .cycle function through some dynamic (runtime) images.  Here is the java script I have:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .slideshow
    {
        margin: auto;
    }
    .slideshow img
    {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-top: 2px;
        background-color: #fff;
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    // trigger an ajax request to the controller action every 5s
    // and inject the returned HTML fragment into a div with id="result"

    window.setInterval(function () {
        $("#GridDatabaseMng").load("/DataBaseMng/Status");
    }, 5000);
});

    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$(function ($) {
        $('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 300,
            timeout: 100,
            pause: 1,
        });
    });

</script>
```

and here is the razor code I will use to populate my .slideshow div tag with a variable number of images...

```
<td>
    <div class="slideshow" ondblclick="window.location.href='/Frame/index?id=@signData.SignDataId'" 
    style="height:160px;padding:2px;border:2px solid red; ">
    <!--
        <img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/image1.bmp")" />
        <img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/image2.bmp")" />
        <img alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/image3.bmp")" />
       -->
        @if (signData.Images != null)
        {
            foreach (Object image in signData.Images)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {                    
                    <img  alt=""   src="@Url.Content(image.ToString())" height="50px" width="50px"
                }
                else
                {                      
                    <img  alt="" src="@Url.Content(image.ToString())" height="50px" width="50px" />                           
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }                   
        }
    </div>
</td>
```

This is some legacy code which "was" working apparently, but I'm not sure what the purpose of the if statement above is as it seems to do exactly the same - I am by no means (clearly) an expert on java or html etc...

What happens is that when I view the page (let's say I have 3 images in signData.Images) I get three images all showing at once which to me makes sense.  I have debugged the javascrip and it is being called.  If I uncomment the hardcoded image tags above (and remove my razor code), the cycle works fine until my setInterval() kicks in, in which case it the cycle stops and the three images are shown all together (like how my razor code shows).

This .cshtml page is a partial view which is returned by the controller via the setInterval() function.  So I'm not sure if it's the setInterval() command which is causing it to stop or the fact that page is (I think( being refreshed/reloaded).

So I guess my two main questions are:
1 - How can I keep my cycle going with the setInterval() function?
2 - How can I make my razor code work to show a dynamic or variable list?

Hopefully I have provided enough information here.  I am using the "cylce-js/jquery.cycle.lite.min.js" script file.

Just to follow up on firebug suggestion, here is a view of what's being generated:

```
<td>
<div class="slideshow" style="height:160px;padding:2px;border:2px solid red; " ondblclick="window.location.href='/Frame/index?id=2'">
<img width="50px" height="50px" src="/Content/Frames/2_1_11_11.bmp" alt="">
<img width="50px" height="50px" src="/Content/Frames/2_2_12_12.bmp" alt="">
<img width="50px" height="50px" src="/Content/Frames/2_3_13_13.bmp" alt="">
</div>
</td>
```

However, I've just realised that this block will be repeated n times (it is contained in a table).  So each row will have the equivalent of this (even though the src values will be different).  Maybe the class name being repeated is causing an issue?  However, not sure if the j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); might have something to do with that???

I will see if i can delve a bit deeper into why the cycle doesn't appear to be working at all, but the above html to me looks correct?

**EDIT 2**

Ok.  After some more experimentation, if I change my setInterval() function to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // trigger an ajax request to the controller action every 5s
    // and inject the returned HTML fragment into a div with id="result"

    window.setInterval(function () {
        $.post('@Url.Content("~/DataBaseMng/Status")', function (data) { $("#GridDatabaseMng").html(data); });
    }, 5000);
});
```

it does exactly the same thing.  That is, stop cycling through and displays all  tags as appropriate in one go in the slideshow element.  Not sure if that means anything, but it seems as soon as I replace the HTML of the owning div tag, it stops the cycle.  The main view containing the partial view is:

```
    <div class="t-widget t-grid" id="GridDatabaseMng" style="width:100%;">
        @Html.Partial("SignDetails", Model) 
</div>
```

so maybe there's something I can do in the "success" of the Post function above to restart the cycle function?

**EDIT 2**

Ok.  Kinda have it going.  I changed my script to be:

```
$("#GridDatabaseMng").load('@Url.Content("~/DatabaseMng/Status")', function () { DoCycle(); });

function DoCycle() {
    j$(function ($) {
        $('#slideShowId').cycle({
                timeout: 100,
                speed: 500
            });
        });
    });
}
```

and this works perfectly well when I have only a single row in my table (which the slideShowId is a column in).  This makes sense I guess because I end up with multiple Ids of slideShowId.

Can anyone tell me how I can create unique Ids (or classnames I guess) in this instance?

The  tag in question is what is above.  (div id="slideShowId" class="slideshow"...)

Thanks

Comment: I would open this page in Firefox and watch the requests in Firebug http://getfirebug.com/ and make sure the requests to get the images are operating correctly.  That should give you some feedback to troubleshoot a little further.  I would also view the source in the browser that your Razor syntax is generating to make sure you are getting the expected HTML you want.

Comment: See edit above. But it definitely seems to be the setInterval() function causing it to stop.  The trouble is, that the actionresult called by setInterval() is needed to populate the img tages in the first place.  So if I can find out how to resolve the issue of cycle stopping when it's called, I might be in luck.  Maybe I should use a different method than load()??

Comment: I noticed that the image tags are not well formed above.  Ending in an '>' instead of a '/>'... that might cause a problem. I am thinking about other causes in the meantime... HTH

Comment: @Jason you can also use the id of the slideshow instead of the class.  Change the jQuery to say $("#IdOfSlideshow").cycle... instead of $(".slideshow").cycle() etc.  Keep the class on their though so your CSS doesn't break...

Comment: That tags are what came straight out of the debug script from firebug - I had another look and it's definitely not showing up that closing tag properly... weird... but I do have them in my actual source.

Comment: I changed it to use the Id instead of the class as you suggested but no luck.  I just added ... id="slideShowId" to my <div> tag.  I'm wondering if from within my Action I can directly call a JQuery function which will restart the cycle again for me?  Do you know if that's possible?  Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I have got it going - I think....

This is what I have ended up...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // trigger an ajax request to the controller action every 5s
        // and inject the returned HTML fragment into a div with id="result"

        RefreshStatus();

        window.setInterval(function () {
            RefreshStatus();
        }, 5000);
    });

    function RefreshStatus() {
        $("#GridDatabaseMng").load('@Url.Content("~/DatabaseMng/Status")', function () { DoCycle(); });
    }

    function DoCycle() {
        j$(function ($) {
            $('.slideshow').each(function () {
                $(this).cycle({
                    timeout: 100,
                    speed: 500
                });
            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

and seems to work ok - so far....  Thanks webtrifusion for your assistance.  You at least gave me areas to investigate for.

Cheers